# Getting 404 Error Response in google chrome extension in React js frontend and express backend

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks

I am trying to create a simple form handling experiment where it will put all fetched data from database and display it to user.
I am using 2 separate projects for frontend and backend.
Frontend is in react and backend is in express js.
Here is my express.js code

```
const express = require("express");
const monggose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const { default: mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const cors = require("cors");
const { Router } = require("express");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// ================= Connectivity ========
monggose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/players");

const cricketerSchema = monggose.Schema({
  rank: Number,
  name: String,
  country: String,
  dob: Date,
  totalRun: Number,
});

const Cricketer = monggose.model("cricketers", cricketerSchema);

// === GET ,POST, DELETE ========
app
  .route("/cricketers")
  .get(function (request, response) {
    Cricketer.find(function (error, foundCricketers) {
      if (!error) {
        response.send(foundCricketers);
      } else {
        response.send(error);
      }
    });
  })
  .post(function (request, response) {
    const c1 = new Cricketer({
      // ==== here Rank is the name of the attribute of form field
      rank: request.body.Rank,
      // ==== here Nank is the name of the attribute of form field
      name: request.body.Name,
      country: request.body.Country,
      dob: request.body.DOB,
      totalRun: request.body.TotalRun,
    });
    c1.save(function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        console.log("Data inserted successfully");
        response.send("Data added successfully...");
      } else {
        console.log(error);
        response.send(error);
      }
    });
  })
  .delete(function (request, response) {
    Cricketer.deleteMany(function (error) {
      if (!error) {
        response.send("All Data Deleted");
      } else {
        response.send(error);
      }
    });
  });

app.listen(3010, function () {
  console.log("Server is running at http://localhost:3010");
});
```

and here is my frontend code.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("zain");
  const [rank, setRank] = useState("5");
  const [country, setCountry] = useState("india");
  const [dob, setDOB] = useState("2023-02-21");
  const [totalrun, setRun] = useState("5000");
  const [cricketers, setCricketers] = useState([]);

  const baseURL = "http://localhost:3010/cricketers";

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(baseURL).then((response) => {
      const x = response.data;
      setCricketers(x);
    });
  }, []);
  function handlesubmit() {
    const collection1 = {
      Name: name,
      Country: country,
      DOB: dob,
      TotalRun: totalrun,
      Rank: rank,
    };
    console.log(collection1);
    useEffect(() => {
      axios
        .post(baseURL, collection1)
        .then(function (response) {
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
    });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <label>Cricketer Rank:</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="Rank"
        value={rank}
        onChange={(e) => setRank(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Cricketer Name:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="Name"
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Cricketer Country:</label>
      <input
        type="text"
        name="Country"
        value={country}
        onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Cricketer DOB:</label>
      <input
        type="date"
        name="DOB"
        value={dob}
        onChange={(e) => setDOB(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <label>Cricketer TotalRun:</label>
      <input
        type="number"
        name="TotalRun"
        value={totalrun}
        onChange={(e) => setRun(e.target.value)}
      />
      <br />
      <button onClick={handlesubmit}>Submit</button>
      <ul>
        {cricketers.map((i) => (
          <li key={i._id}>
            <p>
              {i.name}
              {i.country}
              {i.rank}
              {i.dob}
              {i.totalrun}
            </p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when page is loaded, it's fetching data from database and showing it into react page component.
For post method getting following error.

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at Object.throwInvalidHookError (react-dom.development.js:16227:9)
    at useEffect (react.development.js:1634:21)
    at handlesubmit (App.jsx:29:5)
```

My need is, I want to use functional component only and I have tried with all different solutions,
like fetch and axios.
It's not working.
When I am calling POST method from POSTMAN api it's working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `useEffect` inside `handleSubmit` function. Hooks cannot be called inside a function. They can only be called at top level of a functional component. Refactor the `handleSubmit` function.

Answer (score 0):

Please remove useEffect in your handleSubmit function. GET request must be put inside useEffect, but POST, PUT, PATCH,... don't. It all has to do with when the request is called. You can read further about useEffect to understand this.